# Which Whole Wheat Breads can be crisped on the stove?

Tags: bread

My aunt craves [grilled bread](http://www.foodnetwork.ca/recipe/grilled-garlic-bread-with-thyme-infused-butter/6907/), but her temporary residence for work has only an electric [stove](https://charlesandhudson.com/whats-the-difference-between-a-range-stove-and-cooktop/), and lacks an oven or grill. She loathes (pun intended) microwaves.

What types of Whole Wheat Bread should she buy, to imitate "grilled bread"? She worries that not all grillable breads can be seared on the stove.

Comment: What are you worried about? Are you asking what kind of bread is subjectively best or are you saying you think some kinds of bread are somehow untoastable?

Comment: @Stephie I clarified this in my post. There's no past; this is her first time with imitating grilled bread.

Comment: @Jefromi The latter. I clarified this in my post, but please edit it if still ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any kind of bread can be toasted/grilled. The only things you really have to worry about are whether it has a flat surface to evenly cook and whether it's so crumbly it'll just fall apart. Anything you buy sliced will work, and anything you can cleanly slice will work.

Note that an electric stove is not the easiest way to toast bread, since it isn't designed to radiate heat. The easiest method is probably to butter the bread then put it butter side down in a pan, so the recipe you linked is fine, but plain bread is a bit iffy.